# How to make a text in a label as url, to move to webpage / make a call by click on a text in a label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, nsurlconnection

In my application I have displayed some content in a `tableview` with custom cell.

Custom cell having an `imageView`, button, 4 labels

Each label for

```
1. Name of the candidate
2. Web page address,
3. Email address
4. Phone number.
```

In this I need to highlight the web address label , phone number label and email address label like url's and to do respective actions when user touch them.

like

```
1. open web page when touch on web address label,
2. open email composer sheet when touch on email address label,
3. make a call when touch on phone number label
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a label, if action is needed? Make custom buttons.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much all the same idea, all applications in iOS can be opened with using the format `appShortName://whatyouwantToHandle`, for websites its just `http://myurl`

To make a call, it's `tel`:

```
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

To start composing an email, it's `mailto:`, and it supports GET parameters to fill-out the email.

```
const NSString* mailFormat  = @"mailto:%@?subject=%@&body=%@";
const NSString* mailEmails  = @"person1@gmail.com,person2@gmail.com";
const NSString* mailBody    = @"This is the mail body\n Hi!");
const NSString* mailSubject = @"This is the mail Subject!";

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString*)mailFormat,[mailEmails stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[mailSubject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[mailBody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
```

And to open the web page, as you'd expect, it's just `http:`

```
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:websiteURL];
```

Check the documentation on [`-openURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Make all UILabel's user interaction enabled. Apply tap gesture on each label and implement function call on tap of each label. Implement functions for each label suggested as above.